# Changing all values of string to a certain value

Tags: python, string

```
input = ["AB0","A","BBBB"]
output = ["000","0","0000"]
```

Is there a function like `.replace("", "")` which could take in any input and give a string of zeros with the same number of characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
input  = ["AB0","A","BBBB"]

output = ["0"*len(x) for x in input]
```

or the same:

```
input  = ["AB0","A","BBBB"]
output = []
for x in input:
    output.append("0"*len(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such built-in function, but you can easily write a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for that:

```
>>> input = ["AB0","A","BBBB"]
>>>
>>> ["0" * len(item) for item in input]
['000', '0', '0000']
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this (mostly for fun):

```
>>> input = ["AB0", "A", "BBBB"]
>>> zeros = ''.zfill
>>> [zeros(len(s)) for s in input]
['000', '0', '0000']
```

Note that this only works for filling with `0`.  If you want to fill with different characters then this method won't work.

You could use `ljsut` or `rjust` to fill with different characters...

```
>>> input = ["AB0", "A", "BBBB"]
>>> pad = ''.ljust
>>> [pad(len(s), '1') for s in input]
['111', '1', '1111']
```

However, most of these are really just clever ways to do it.  They aren't faster:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("[pad(len(s), '1') for s in input]", 'from __main__ import pad, input')
1.3355789184570312
>>> timeit.timeit("['1' * len(s) for s in input]", 'from __main__ import pad, input')
0.8812301158905029
>>> zeros = ''.zfill
>>> timeit.timeit("[zeros(len(s)) for s in input]", 'from __main__ import zeros, input')
1.110482931137085
```

though, depending on your particular preferences/background, you might find one way clearer to understand than another (and that's worth something)...

FWIW, my first instinct is to use the multiplication method as proposed in 
[Selcuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40858071/748858) so that's probably what I find most easy to read and understandable...

Comment: what about `["".rjust(len(s), "H") for s in input]`? for example

Comment: @TheClonerx -- Yeah, I was thinking about that too.  Since you suggested it and I was thinking about it, I suppose I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python 're' module, like following:

```
import re

input = ["AB0","A","BBBB"]
output = []

for value in input:
  str = re.sub(".","0",value)
  output.append(str)

print output
```

Answer (score 0):

```
map(lambda x:"0"*len(x),["AB0","A","BBB"])
```